# windows keydown listeners in C

Tags: c++, c, windows

I am having a very hard time finding resources that talk about the windows message system. Mainly the keydown constant variables.  I need to know what const varibles I need to listen for all keypress especially the arrow keys for C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a **winuser.h** header file found in your SDK's installation which lists all the VK_ (Virtual Keys) which are key codes that you require, specifically VK_UP, VK_RIGHT, VK_LEFT and VK_DOWN for the up/right/left/down cursor keys respectively.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375731(v=VS.85).aspx lists all of the virtual key codes. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646280(VS.85).aspx explains how they are carried in WM_KEYDOWN